# How do I identify what hardware button is pressed?

Tags: hardware, acpi, button

I'd like to assign a certain task to execute when a  specific hardware button is pressed.
My question is how should I proceed to achieve this behaviour?
Where is the information about the assigned hardware button stored and what should I know about acpi hooks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal. Run this

```
$ xev
```

hit a key, output in xev will spew out, telling you the hardware characteristic that your OS is seeing.  I've had to do this when the right control key seemed to do nothing. And it turned out the keyboard layout was not set to receive that key.

Only if the OS sees your key will it be useful to configure keyboard shortcuts that previous answer suggested.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thanks 
xev | grep keycode

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague but it sounds like what you’re looking for is to setup a custom keyboard shortcut. If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 then you can easily setup your own shortcuts by following the instructions at [THIS LINK](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html). I have an extended keyboard with buttons like “favorites” that I never use so I set them up as shortcuts for other things that I do use. Depending on what task you want to execute this could be exactly what you need.